# Grow LI elements to fit a fixed width

Tags: html, html-lists

How to grow the `li` elements in the way, that all the four `li` elements consume the complete 900 pixels space and add a little gap between the elements. And why is there already a gap now - I have none defined?

```
<html><head><title></title></head>
<style type="text/css">
#box { width: 900px; border: solid 1px black; }

#menu {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li a, #menu li a:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu li a:hover, #menu li a:active {
    background-color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

</style>
<body>

<div id="box">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Mozilla Firefox &amp; Thunderbird</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OpenOffice</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Microsoft Office Visio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Apache OpenOffice 3.0.0</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline blocks behave weirdly in the fact that they render whitespace.  The gap shown between items is the new line characters in your code.  You can either remove the new line characters as I have shown in the code below (or at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UyQEK/).  If you want to keep the HTML clean, and not have to do this removal of whitespace, use float left on the elements instead of display: inline-block and do a clearfix on the parent to set the height.

```
<div id="box">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Mozilla Firefox &amp; Thunderbird</a></li><li><a href="#">OpenOffice</a></li><li><a href="#">Microsoft Office Visio</a></li><li><a href="#">Apache OpenOffice 3.0.0</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Made the classic mistake of forgetting to check to ensure I answered the whole question.  I have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UyQEK/1/ to show the actual answer to utilize the entire bar rather then just get rid of your spaces.  The basis of the solution was floating the elements and giving them each a width of 25% and applying a clearfix to the ul element.

Hope that solves the whole thing this time.